# Changing the value key in pom.xml on ec2 instance

Tags: maven, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-security, microservices

We have a springboot app deployed in CloudFoundry and the settings/configuration are located in the EC2 instance (pom.xml).

I need to change a portion of the configuration file (service ip) pointing to a new location.
If changes are made, do i need to recompile all the springboot apps/services or should i only restart the application/services?

Comment: If you mean updating `application.properities`, restart would do most of the time. Updating your `pom.xml` means updating your code and that would require compilation.

Comment: Hi Orvyl. the pom.xml is a parent pom file connected to a multi-module project. so if the 16 services is dependent on the parent pom file, would that still require to recompile all dependent services?

Comment: This depends on the impact of the change. Most of the time, we use parent pom to hold common config and dependencies, and if the update is like updating a dependency version, you need to recompile the whole sub modules if you want that version(update) to take effect. REMEMBER: `pom` doesn't have any effect after compilation.